# Why iOS system grays have a slight blue hue?

Tags: color, interface-design, ios, style, apple

The light system gray defined by Apple Guidelines for iOS12 (and used by the default color scheme of the UI controls), is defined as #EFEFF4 (HSB(240,2,96)). It means that the hue is a little bit blue. The new guidelines (iOS13), also use the same Hue/Sat combination but with more variations for the Brightness.

I'll like to learn why Apple designers choose to do that. I imagine that the intention was to change the overall UI tone (like the Glaze painting technique). But I wonder if there is any additional information about that

Why blue? It looks better to the eye or to the iPhone color profile? Or it was a decision to make it look better with space gray color of the iPhone/iPad?

Comment: I'm just guessing her: I have noticed that people (my clients) have a tendency to like images with a golden/orange tint more than images with cooler/blue tones. I guess it's because it gives associations to sunshine/warmth. Having a slightly blue background on everything will make all images seem a tiny bit warmer in comparison which might attract consumers?

Comment: I'd guess the opposite reason: typical viewing of the phone or iPad will be in either sunlight (3-5K kelvin colour temp or above) or in artificial light, much of which has a slight orange cast - by slightly blueing the UI, they renomalise and make their UI seem cleaner white - least, that'd be my guess.

Comment: Excellent guess @GerardFalla I'd suspect, if there is a technical reason you may be very close to the mark.

Comment: I follow you @GerardFalla. It sounds plausible. I'm just wondering (still guessing here): If you only see Apple UI it might not matter much whether it's completely neutral because your eyes will quickly adapt and believe that the gray you are seeing is in fact neutral - no matter if it's slightly orange or slightly blue. But content from other sources (which doesn't have that slightly blue Apple correction) will look warmer in comparison. So the UI might look more neutral, but it will force other content to look more orange. Or am I totally wrong here?

Comment: Well, just from a design standpoint.. a rich black is *always* more appealing than a straight black.

Comment: A paper salesman once told me that neutral color is a social construct, as well as a ambient light construct. So people living higher latitudes equate blesih tints with clean and white, while people closer to the equator like orange sometimes brownish whites and grays more. But also if you pik the whitiest paper in your portfolio before flying form 60th parallel to equator you will find that its not whitest paper at the equator.

Comment: There seem to be some valid theories posed here, but have you ever considered that there might me no reason, other than the fact the designer just liked it, and was not actually concerned that the grey is not technically neutral?  Choice of colours is often entirely subjective. Perhaps you are reading too much into it.

Comment: @Billy Kerr Yes, I think that probably it was for an aesthetic reason. The origin of my question has to do with creating a color palette for a web app. While working on the grayscale, I started to compare some of the grays in our mobile app (that matches iOS). The slight blue grays look better for my particular case, so I was wondering if other designers do the same...or maybe if I was lucky I can get some insight from that iOS design decision. When you put a "standard gray" (same values for each RGB) side-by-side with the blueish gray the color temperature difference is noticeable.